# Is there any way in Yii2 to dynamically change URL without reloading? a part from pjax

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2

My point is; I use Ajax to load some part of the page but when the part is loaded I would like to change the url in the navigation bar.

I can go for the history.js as suggested in this post but I would like to know if there is a solution within Yii2 without using extensible library.

I don't wanna use pjax because I have some complex processing using pjax will make it more complex for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yii2 don't deal with such kind of functionality. It'pure JS thing, you can use it without additional libraries. All major browsers already support it: [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=history).

Use `history.pushState()` to update current url and `popstate` event to update page content when user navigates through history.